# jQuery In-Field Labels with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've got a problem with jQuery's In-Field Labels plugin.  Right now, it is working completely perfectly on my page.  It is a super awesome plugin that does a really good job.

But I need to hack it a bit to extend the functionality:

I need it to work with AJAX form data.  In other words, I am trying to populate my form via AJAX.  The plugin doesn't work properly when fields are dynamically filled in, the plugin doesn't even notice the input value.  So Instead of fading out the label like it should, the label stays, so I essentially have the label and the field value overlapping each other.

Do you have any idea how I could go about hacking this plugin to work with AJAX values?

```
/*
 * In-Field Label jQuery Plugin
 * http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield.html
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Doug Neiner
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * Uses the same license as jQuery, see:
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
 *
 * @version 0.1
 */
(function($){

    $.InFieldLabels = function(label,field, options){
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of each element
        base.$label = $(label);
        base.label = label;

        base.$field = $(field);
        base.field = field;

        base.$label.data("InFieldLabels", base);
        base.showing = true;

        base.init = function(){
            // Merge supplied options with default options
            base.options = $.extend({},$.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions, options);

            // Check if the field is already filled in
            if(base.$field.val() != ""){
                base.$label.hide();
                base.showing = false;
            };

            base.$field.focus(function(){
                base.fadeOnFocus();
            }).blur(function(){
                base.checkForEmpty(true);
            }).bind('keydown.infieldlabel',function(e){
                // Use of a namespace (.infieldlabel) allows us to
                // unbind just this method later
                base.hideOnChange(e);
            }).change(function(e){
                base.checkForEmpty();
            }).bind('onPropertyChange', function(){
                base.checkForEmpty();
            });
        };

        // If the label is currently showing
        // then fade it down to the amount
        // specified in the settings
        base.fadeOnFocus = function(){
            if(base.showing){
                base.setOpacity(base.options.fadeOpacity);
            };
        };

        base.setOpacity = function(opacity){
            base.$label.stop().animate({ opacity: opacity }, base.options.fadeDuration);
            base.showing = (opacity > 0.0);
        };

        // Checks for empty as a fail safe
        // set blur to true when passing from
        // the blur event
        base.checkForEmpty = function(blur){
            if(base.$field.val() == ""){
                base.prepForShow();
                base.setOpacity( blur ? 1.0 : base.options.fadeOpacity );
            } else {
                base.setOpacity(0.0);
            };
        };

        base.prepForShow = function(e){
            if(!base.showing) {
                // Prepare for a animate in...
                base.$label.css({opacity: 0.0}).show();

                // Reattach the keydown event
                base.$field.bind('keydown.infieldlabel',function(e){
                    base.hideOnChange(e);
                });
            };
        };

        base.hideOnChange = function(e){
            if(
                (e.keyCode == 16) || // Skip Shift
                (e.keyCode == 9) // Skip Tab
              ) return; 

            if(base.showing){
                base.$label.hide();
                base.showing = false;
            };

            // Remove keydown event to save on CPU processing
            base.$field.unbind('keydown.infieldlabel');
        };

        // Run the initialization method
        base.init();
    };

    $.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions = {
        fadeOpacity: 0.5, // Once a field has focus, how transparent should the label be
        fadeDuration: 300 // How long should it take to animate from 1.0 opacity to the fadeOpacity
    };


    $.fn.inFieldLabels = function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            // Find input or textarea based on for= attribute
            // The for attribute on the label must contain the ID
            // of the input or textarea element
            var for_attr = $(this).attr('for');
            if( !for_attr ) return; // Nothing to attach, since the for field wasn't used


            // Find the referenced input or textarea element
            var $field = $(
                "input#" + for_attr + "[type='text']," + 
                "input#" + for_attr + "[type='password']," + 
                "textarea#" + for_attr
                );

            if( $field.length == 0) return; // Again, nothing to attach

            // Only create object for input[text], input[password], or textarea
            (new $.InFieldLabels(this, $field[0], options));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   base.init = function(){
        // Merge supplied options with default options
        base.options = $.extend({},$.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions, options);

        // Check if the field is already filled in
        if(base.$field.val() != ""){
            //base.$label.hide();
            base.setOpacity(0.0);
            base.showing = false;
        }
        else //Added by Anand
        {
            base.setOpacity( blur ? 1.0 : base.options.fadeOpacity );
            base.showing = true;
        };

        base.$field.focus(function(){
            base.fadeOnFocus();
        }).blur(function(){
            base.checkForEmpty(true);
        }).bind('keydown.infieldlabel',function(e){
            // Use of a namespace (.infieldlabel) allows us to
            // unbind just this method later
            base.hideOnChange(e);
        }).change(function(e){
            base.checkForEmpty();
        }).bind('onPropertyChange', function(){
            base.checkForEmpty();
        }).bind('keyup',function(e){ //Added by Anand
            base.checkForEmpty();
        });
    };
```

change your init function like above. Here I have added the else part for check the empty values. Then whenever you fill or clear the values in text fields, just call the infield label creating function again, like "$("label").inFieldLabels();"

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up not using inFieldLabels, but this solution looks like it would work.